# How to know which button is pressed from UICollectionViewController in another view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am creating one application in which 3 button grid used.
I used UICollectionViewController for that and add buttons to UICollectionViewCell
Also add target for each button click event
below code

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
             cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "first", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
             cell.btn.setTitle("1st", forState: .Normal)
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "second", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            cell.btn.setTitle("2nd", forState: .Normal)
        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {            
            cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "third", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            cell.btn.setTitle("3rd", forState: .Normal)
        }
}
```

Whenever button is clicked view controller navigate to another view controller
code for that

```
var destinationViewController : UIViewController!
func third(){
   destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddInventory") as! UIViewController
   navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

but navigation to same view controller for any button clicked
because I use segment view controller and for particular index different view will displayed so I have to check which button is selected from collection view
I used tag for checking

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
```

but its not working
I can not access tag

In short my question is how to check which button(from collectionview)is clicked when push to another view controller
Thanx in advance

Comment: You functions (first, second, third) should have parameter "sender". This way the sender will be the button which was tapped.

Comment: Why can not access tag?

Comment: applocation crash when I access tag using withViewTag()

Comment: @GunjaPatel Post your code about using `viewWithTag`

Comment: I am trying to add code for accessing tag in destination view controller viewdidload method like this                                                                        var home = HomeCollectionViewController()
        home.collectionView?.viewWithTag(7)                                                HomeCollectionViewController is my class in which I use collection

Comment: @GunjaPatel Check my answer. You just need to implement one method like `buttonClicked`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
}

func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton?) {
    let tag = sender.tag

    let destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddInventory") as! DestinationViewController
    destinationViewController.fromTag = tag
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: I modify my func like your answer but it give error that           UIViewController does not have a member named 'fromTag'                                  can u please tell me meaning of "fromTag" which u use

Comment: It will be declared inside the `destinationViewController` then you will know which button is pressed in the `destinationViewController`. You have to create a custom viewController(subclass of `UIViewController`).

Comment: its worked !!! only change one thing that casting of destinationviewcontroller as a view Controller.    In my case DestinationViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a property for your destinationViewController.
e.g. showIndex

Then you can modify your func third:

```
func third(){
   destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddInventory") as! UIViewController
   destinationViewController.showIndex = 3;
   navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Don't know if I understand your question clearly.

Comment: can not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

```
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            if indexPath.row == 0 {
                 cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "first:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.tag = indexpath.row
                 cell.btn.setTitle("1st", forState: .Normal)
            }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
                cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "second:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.tag = indexpath.row
                cell.btn.setTitle("2nd", forState: .Normal)
            }else if indexPath.row == 2 {            
                cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: "third:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
cell.tag = indexpath.row
                cell.btn.setTitle("3rd", forState: .Normal)
            }
    }
```

for target user this

```
func third(sender:UIButton?){
  var tag:Int = sender.tag
   destinationViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddInventory") as! UIViewController
   navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: true)

}
```